# Server Polling of Android devices' location

Tags: android

I need to track some company devices. I know I can make my app periodically send back their where-about like every few minutes or so.

But I'm trying to cut down the unnecessary traffics and make the server polls for locations when it is needed only.

Something like:
1. Server executes: TellMeYourLocationNow(deviceid) 
2. targeted device acknowledges and send back its location

How do I request the device(s) sending back their current location to me, only when I need them?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Google Cloud Message (GCM) to send a push notification, which can start the Location functionality on your device (or do pretty much anything).  The server can generate the GCM notification when it wants location from the device.

Comment: Sounds like just what I needed, will give it a shot and post back. Thanks!